# Group by and foreach

Tags: php, sql, foreach, group-by

I want to print only once the title and all related images id_post

table IMAGES

```
id_images | dir_image | post_id
     1      image1.jpg   1
     2      image2.jpg   1
     3      image3.jpg   1
     4      image4.jpg   1
     5      image5.jpg   2
     6      image6.jpg   2
     7      image7.jpg   2
     8      image8.jpg   2
```

table POSTS

```
id_post   |          slug        |   title
 1           title_post            Title Post 
 2           title_post_2          Title Post 2
```

PHP code:

```
$slug = $_GET['slug'];
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts, images 
                      WHERE posts.id_post = images.post_id 
                      AND slug=:slug");
 $stmt->execute(array(":slug"=>$_GET['slug']));

 while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
 {
 ?> 

<h1><?php print utf8_encode($row['title']);?></h1>


<?php
}
?>
```

Accessing the page "Title post 2", the result is:

```
Title post 2
image5.jpg

Title post 2
image6.jpg

Title post 2
image7.jpg

Title post 2
image8.jpg
```

How to get the result:

```
Title post 2
image5.jpg
image6.jpg
image7.jpg
image8.jpg
```

How I enter the SQL statement the "group by" to group images:

```
SELECT * FROM posts, images 
                     WHERE posts.id_post = images.post_id 
                     AND slug=:slug
```

And then inside the while inserting a foreach with the images of the group by?

```
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
     {
     ?> 

    <h1><?php print utf8_encode($row['title']);?></h1>


    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Inserting if not solve for me, it will be necessary to create several ifs

Comment: no idea what the question is

Comment: Me too. Can you add an example of desired SQL result? (If you want a SQL result).

Comment: @Dagon I added information to my question

Comment: in loop store title, if it doesn't change dont output it

Comment: you just asked the same question again, just use the group by clause in your sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's some easy and fast and if your "join" images are few, not many.

Your group by, use a GROUP BY and get all images concatenated by SEPARATOR with GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT 
  posts.*,
  COUNT(0) total, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(dir_image SEPARATOR '|') images
FROM 
  posts
  INNER JOIN images ON (posts.id_post = images.post_id )
WHERE
  slug=:slug
GROUP BY
  id_post
```

This is your loop, create an array exploding the SEPARATOR over field "images" and do the loop

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
    $aImages = explode('|', $row['images']);
    ?>
    <h1><?php print utf8_encode($row['title']); ?></h1>
    <div>
        <ul>
        <?php
            echo '<li>' . implode('</li><li>', $aImages) . '</li>'
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Or

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
    $aImages = explode('|', $row['images']);
    ?>
    <h1><?php print utf8_encode($row['title']); ?></h1>
    <div>
        <?php
        foreach ($aImages as $sImage) {
        ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $sImage;?>"><?php echo $sImage; ?></a>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank´s @MauricioFlorez it worked perfectly :D

Comment: You could help me input the COUNT images in sql statement?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do it in procedural PHP, you could do something like this:

```
$runningTitle = '';

while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) { 

    if ($row['title'] != $runningTitle) {
        $runningTitle = $row['title'];
        print "<h1>";
        print utf8_encode($row['title']);
        print "</h1>";
    }

    // now render images.

}
```

However I would recommend using a more object orientated approach to build the html string and then return it as a single string, to echo at the end, rather than rendering everything out procedurally. It's often tidier to complete all your program logic before rendering a page, rather than rendering while you are still asking the code to make decisions.

You are using PHP in it's traditional form - as a templating language. It has come a long way since then.

Comment: Thanks @TimOgilvy I am trying to learn PHP object oriented, I hope soon get